# Error uploading images using Django, Google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-admin

I'm building a web app using Django for Google App Engine, with the [djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) library.  I'm stuck on getting image uploads working via the admin interface.  My `models.py` is:

```
class Bio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    about = models.TextField()
    email = models.TextField()
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/bios/", null=True, blank=True)
```

When I try to upload an image in the default admin interface, both locally and on the appspot website, I get: "ImportError: No module named Image"

But! -- when I run `manage.py shell` I am able to successfully `import Image` and `from PIL import Image`, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  Any ideas?

Comment: PIL is not supported on App Engine (with Python 2.5; it works on 2.7). Django's shell doesn't enforce the App Engine sandboxing restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#field-types says that ImageField isn't supported.

Try uploading to blobstore (see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html). That basically uses an intervening handler that stores the image, handing back a blob key instead of a file to your destination handler.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?  Can I use the default admin interface, or do I need to make a custom class somehow?  I found [this site](http://blog.sserrano.com/post/479962742/blobstore-upload-with-django-form-validation-example) which explains how to make a custom form page, but I'd like to be able to just put something like a BlobField in my models.py (which currently gives an error).

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Uploading_a_Blob

Answer (score 2):

Django's ImageField uses PIL to check if the uploaded file is actually an image. The problem is, PIL was not available on AppEngine server initially, so you had to use AppEngine's [Images API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/images/overview.html) instead.

While googling around, I found [this implementation](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1805/) of ImageField widget for AppEngine, that uses google.appengine.api.images instead of PIL.

Seems like AppEngine supports PIL on Python 2.7 now though. So if you're developping a Python 2.7 app on AppEngine, all you need is to turn the support of PIL on [in app.yaml](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27.html#Configuring_Libraries)